# If $W = \operatorname{Span}(1, 1, 3)$ then $\operatorname{proj}_w$ $\perp (9, -6, 10)$ is:

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $W = \operatorname{Span}(1, 1, 3)$ then $\operatorname{proj}_w$ $\perp (9, -6, 10)$ is:

Can someone explain how to go about this? I got $(-9, 6, 1)$, I don't think it's right.

Comment: To project onto a subspace, you take an orthonormal basis in that subspace and then sum over the projections onto each element of the basis. So if $\{w_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an orthonormal basis of some subspace of $V$ called $W$, and $v\in V$, then $\text{proj}_{W}(v)=\sum_{i\in I}\langle v,w_i\rangle w_i$. I did not obtain your answer, but my arithmetic is notoriously bad on occasion. How did you go about this, then?

Answer (score 0):

No, that can't be right- the projection of a vector onto a subspace is **in** that subspace.  Basically you want to find a vector of the form a(1, 1, 3)+ b(p, q, r)= (9, -6, 10) with (p, q, r) being perpendicular to (1, 1, 3): p+ q+ 3r= 0.  That last condition can be written p= -q- 3r.  So we must have a+ pb= a- bq- 3br= 9, a+ bq= -6, and 3a_ br= 10.  That is three equations in four unknowns so one will be a parameter.